# Raspbeerry Pi boot into console after booting into desktop

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, boot, gui, raspi-config

I set up my pi 2 to boot into raspbian GUI desktop when starting up (under raspi-config). However, the system boot into desktop first when starting up. And a few seconds later, the system boot into console. Is there any way to stay in GUI desktop?

Comment: Does a console pop up? Or does the desktop appear to crash and give you a terminal error?

Comment: The desktop appear for only about a few seconds before console takes over. No error messages. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I tried to install retro-pie + rasbian desktop + rpi-update

I resolved this problem following this steps:

Configure in your retropie script setup, boot in console text insted desktop.

Configure in raspi config, boot in console too

Edit this file /home/pi/.bashrc

```
sudo nano /home/pi/.bashrc
```

Go to the bottom of the file and add `startx` after `echo -e "\n$out"`

```
  echo -e "\n$out
  if [ "$(tset -q)" == "linux" ]; then startx; fi
}
```

The conditional avoid run startx when you open a terminal in Desktop.

/home/pi/.bashrc file is the same file that show the temperature and others data when start rasbian console.

If you don't have retro-pie this file is different for you but you can edit similarly.